# Kafka Connect replication factor for license topic

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to run `Kafka-Connect` locally with `docker-compose`. Much as I like Confluent products and Kafka, it's sometimes a huge quest to pass some config or find one consistent example.
In my docker-compose file, I'm using `6.0.0` versions for `broker`, `zk`, `sr` and `kafka-connect` right now, but I've tried older versions as well.

The broker(`confluentinc/cp-server:6.0.0`) fails with:

> INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 1]: Error processing create topic
> request CreatableTopic(name='_confluent-license', numPartitions=1,
> replicationFactor=3, assignments=[],
> configs=[CreateableTopicConfig(name='cleanup.policy',
> value='compact'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='min.insync.replicas',
> value='2')], linkName=null, mirrorTopic=null)
> (kafka.server.AdminManager)

And I simply don't know how to pass `confluent.topic.replication.factor` as env vars to my workers. I've added both:

```
      CONNECT_CONFLUENT_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONFLUENT_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
```

...but they are both ignored.
What's more, I can't even find `_confluent-license` mentioned in [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-sftp/source-connector/license_config.html#cp-license) anywhere, only `_confluent-command`.

How can I possibly make connect work locally inside `docker-compose` and without setting up 3 brokers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broker is failing, because that topic is created from it, so you want the variable on the broker

```
KAFKA_CONFLUENT_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Otherwise, you want `cp-kafka` image, not `cp-server`

Comment: Indeed, @OneCricketeer, I finally got it right before I saw your answer. But thanks anyway! My Confluent adoption after several years working with bare Kafka is bumpy sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As OneCricketeer pointed out, the value must be set in the broker container, and that also explains why it's broker container that fails, not connect workers. That definitely makes sense. **Broker can't fail because of a misconfigured clients.**

What probably made it a lot more confusing to find a solution is that the env var and configuration property for license topic replication factor do not follow a regular pattern where env var is an uppercases configuration property with dots replaced with underscores(and prefix where applicable). In reality we get:
`confluent.topic.replication.factor` -> `KAFKA_CONFLUENT_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR`

Comment: There is a pattern... All server.properties settings get prefixed by KAFKA_, then all dots become underscores, then all uppercased. The Confluent documentation explains the same